# Bing Ads API authentication issue

Tags: api, bing

I'm trying to pull data through the bing ads api. I've followed the walkthrough to get an authentication and a refresh token with the php SDK however I now need to use the stored refresh token to call the api to get information.

The SDK documentation suggests using the following to set auth credentials:

```
$authorizationData = (new AuthorizationData())
    ->withAuthentication($AuthenticationGoesHere)
    ->withCustomerId($CustomerIdGoesHere)
    ->withAccountId($AccountIdGoesHere)
    ->withDeveloperToken($DeveloperTokenGoesHere);
```

however it doesn't explain what the $AuthenticationGoesHere should be/how it's constructed. I've tried the respective tokens but to no avail. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet from a complete [web example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/walkthrough-web-application-php?view=bingads-13) that shows how to use the refresh token:

```php
$refreshToken = $_SESSION['AuthorizationData']->Authentication->OAuthTokens->RefreshToken;
if($refreshToken != null)
{
    $_SESSION['AuthorizationData']->Authentication->RequestOAuthTokensByRefreshToken($refreshToken);
}
```

Does this help?